# Multiple celery server but same redis broker executing task twice

Tags: django, celery

When I inspect `celery -A proj inspect active_queues` I see two servers showing their queues they are listening to and they are pointing to same default queue name `celery`. Still the task issued by django app gets executed twice by both servers(Once by each celery server - so two times).

I can see the transport type is also `direct` - the default one.

On my local task gets executed once so I am sure that the task is called only once by my django app.

What can I be missing here?

Comment: Closing this question as this was because of a custom wrapper over celery which was not using queue properly. Nothing to do with celery at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i looked up the docs, i think you need to set celerybeat-scheduler in your settings.py which makes sure tasks are being scheduled by a single scheduler.

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celerybeat-scheduler

Comment: mm I don't think I understand this. Both celeryservers listen to one database server on which redis is installed and redis run on say `1234` port so both celeryservers will have same `BROKER_URL` `redis://:<password>@<databaseserver_ip>:<port>`. Could you please elaborate what are you trying to say?

Comment: Isnt this for the periodic tasks?

Answer (score 0):

On Redis you can set the current database for the application you are running, setting the database will separate the information to use different apps.

If you are using Django the configuration is 
`CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = {number of the database}`
If you are not using Django i beleive the configuration is `CELERY_REDIS_DB` or `redis_db` depending on your celery version

For instance for your first application could be `CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = 1`
For the second application could be  `CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = 2`
and for your local development could be `CELERY_BROKER_VHOST = 99`

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#id8